# Braintree Paypal with DropIn UI and Vault not working

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I've been reading the documentation for the past 3 days and haven't been able to figure it out (or at least get it to work).

What I want is the Drop-In UI that remembers previously added Paypal accounts so the user only has to click the account name again, so I'll be using the Vault flow.

What I've done is as follows

1. Retrieve a braintree token from my server
2. Define the URL scheme as:

   ```
   android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
       android:launchMode="singleTask">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
   ```
3. Initialize a BraintreeFragment and the Dropin UI using the following code:

   ```
   braintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(getActivity(), 
   braintreeToken);
   braintreeFragment.addListener(PaymentFragment.this);

   DropInRequest dropInRequest = new DropInRequest()
           .clientToken(braintreeToken)
           .collectDeviceData(true);
   startActivityForResult(dropInRequest.getIntent(context), 1);

   @Override
   public void onPaymentMethodNonceCreated(PaymentMethodNonce paymentMethodNonce)
   {
       if (paymentMethodNonce instanceof PayPalAccountNonce)
       {
           PayPalAccountNonce paypalAccountNonce = (PayPalAccountNonce) paymentMethodNonce;
           Toasty.info(context, paypalAccountNonce.getFirstName()).show();
       }
   }
   ```

When I run the app, the drop-in UI doesn't show up, and instead I see a white area at the bottom of the screen with a progress circle.

If I remove the `BraintreeFragment` and `onPaymentMethodNonceCreated`, the DropIn UI shows up normally but pressing the Paypal button does nothing other than dismissing the UI.

What am I doing wrong here? I have seen plenty of tutorials for CreditCard implementation but none for paypal that can help me.

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact support at https://help.braintreepayments.com/.

In order to better assist you I would recommend writing in to our Support team to start a ticket. We may need to review some information within your specific account to better troubleshoot you, which won't work as well through a SO thread.

Once you write into our Support team someone will be able to assist you.

Comment: same issue here. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @TarunKumar wish I could help you bro but I've forgotten how I fixed this :/ If I remember, I'll try to add the answer here.

Comment: @TarunKumar im waiting bro. :)